# Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` Found: [[0.5 0.5 0.5 ... 0.5 0.5 0.5]]

Tags: python, encryption

input_img = Input(shape=(48400,))

encoded = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(12800, activation='relu')(encoded)

## Convert encoded tensor to numpy array

get_encoded = K.function([input_img], [encoded])
encoded_array = get_encoded([np.zeros((1, 48400))])[0]

## Padding the encoded array to match the block size

block_size = 16
padded_encoded_array = pkcs7_pad(encoded_array.tobytes(), block_size)

## Encryption of the encoded data

encrypted = aes_encrypt(padded_encoded_array, key, iv)

## Decryption of the encrypted data

decrypted = aes_decrypt(encrypted, key, iv)

## Remove padding from the decrypted data

decrypted = np.frombuffer(pkcs7_unpad(decrypted), dtype=np.float32).reshape(encoded_array.shape)

decoded = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decrypted)
decoded = Dense(48400, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

## Concatenate decoded with itself

concatenated = Concatenate()([decoded, decoded])

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=concatenated)

autoencoder.summary()

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 29>()
27 concatenated = Concatenate()([decoded, decoded])
28
---> 29 autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=concatenated)
30
31 autoencoder.summary()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py in _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs(self)
870             if not hasattr(x, "_keras_history"):
871                 cls_name = self.**class**.**name**
--> 872                 raise ValueError(
873                     f"Output tensors of a {cls_name} model must be "
874                     "the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` "

ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: [[0.5 0.5 0.5 ... 0.5 0.5 0.5]]

May I know how to solve this error ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.